# Generic method with inferred generic arguments

Tags: c#, generics

I have the following code to create an expression of a func for accessing a property of a class

```
public static Expression<Func<TObj, TProperty>> BuildGet<TObj, TProperty>(PropertyInfo property)
{
    Type type = typeof(TObj);
    ParameterExpression arg = Expression.Parameter(type, "x");
    var prop = Expression.Property(arg, property);

    return Expression.Lambda<Func<TObj, TProperty>>(prop, arg);
}
```

The problem is, is that I have to pass in `TObj` and `TProperty` even though they are known (properties on `PropertyInfo` class - `.DeclaringType` and `.PropertyType`).

Is there a way around this so I don't explicitly have to pass them in?

The return type must remain as `Expression<Func<TObj, TProperty>>`

Comment: Ask yourself why you have a PropertyInfo as an argument ...

Comment: because it came from some reflection that needs to plug in to some existing functionality (requiring the Expression<Func<TObj, TProperty>>). I know its not a biggie, just wondered if there was some advanced generics technique I was unaware of

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If the return type has to remain `Func<TObj, TProperty>` then the method has to stay generic. You will have to specify the types at *compile-time*. That's the thing - although `PropertyInfo` knows the types, that information is only available at *execution* time, whereas the compiler needs to know the type information in order to check that you're using the value properly, etc. It can't possibly know what the execution-time values of the properties will be.

If you could change the return type to just `Expression` then you could create an `Expression<Func<TObj, TProperty>>` with the appropriate types at execution time, but just return it as an `Expression`. You wouldn't be able to use the return value in a compile-time type-safe way without casting, but it may be helpful...

Comment: Yeah i think thats my only alternative. Can't decide whether id rather cast an Expression or pass in the Ts hmmmm. Thanks :)

Answer (score 1):

How is the compiler supposed to infer the type of `TObj`?  You are not passing any argument to the function that is of that type.

You could try something like this:

```
public static Expression<Func<TObj, TProperty>> BuildGet<TObj, TProperty>
    (TObj obj, TProperty property) { ... }
```

which would allow the compiler to infer the types of `TObj` and `TProperty` but that would mean you would have to refactor your method as you are using the `PropertyInfo` parameter currently.

Comment: yeah I know that's the problem, I'm looking for a solution :) I take it that means there isn't one :(

Comment: You can't pass TProperty, it requires that you have an instance.